# How to access a field outside of rootProperty from itemTpl's XTemplate in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

Say, we have the following in a store:

```
{
    "document": {
        "success": "true",
        "totalAllocation": "40000000.00",
        "fundAllocation": [
            {
                "fundName": "Zais Opportunity Ltd Class B",
                "allocation": "10000000.00"
            },
            {
                "fundName": "Metacapital Mortgage Opportunities Ltd",
                "allocation": "10000000.00"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

And what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<div>',
        '<span>{fundName}</span>',
        '<span>{[this.getPercentage(values.allocation, parent.totalAllocation)]}%</span>',
    '</div>',
    {
        getPercentage: function (allocation, totalAllocation) {
            return Ext.Number.toFixed(allocation / totalAllocation, 2);
        }
    }
)
```

But, of course, this doesn't work since 'parent' in this scope is empty.

Any idea how to fetch the value of the totalAllocation field inside XTemplate's fundtion to display the percentage allocated to the current fund in a list item?
Workarounds are welcomed as well.

Comment: Is `document` the store root?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your data code it looks like `document` is the store root because there is a `success` property underneath it. Assuming that is the case, you can use the store reader's `rawData` property to get a reference to the value before you create the template. Then you can simply use the referenced value in the `getPercentage` function.

Your code does not show where you are creating this `itemTpl` in your class so I am assuming that you are creating this `itemTpl` inside the `initComponent` of the view you are instantiating.

I have no idea what type of component you are trying to create here other than the fact that it has an `itemTpl` config property which could be any subclass of `Ext.view.AbstractView`.

So I will assume that you are trying to use this in a gridpanel's view because that is the most common subclass of `Ext.view.AbstractView`.

Here's some code examples.

**Example 1:**

```
Ext.define('YourApp.view.TemplateGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    // column configs etc...

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
            templateStore = Ext.getStore('TemplateStoreId'),
            totalAllocation = templateStore.proxy.reader.rawData.totalAllocation;

        me.viewConfig.itemTpl = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<div>',
                '<span>{fundName}</span>',
                '<span>{[this.getPercentage(values.allocation)]}%</span>',
            '</div>',
            {
                getPercentage: function (allocation) {
                    return Ext.Number.toFixed(allocation / totalAllocation, 2);
                }
            }
        )
    }
});
```

Example 1 wouldn't work if you want to be able to load the store again (after initialization), it also assumes that your view store is already loaded. Here's another example showing the component set-up to handle multiple loads of the store without being recreated, it also assumes that the store is *not* loaded at the time when you create the view:

**Example 2**

```
Ext.define('YourApp.view.TemplateGrid', { // or whatever you are calling it
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    // column configs etc...

    totalAllocation = 0, // add this as a view property

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
            templateStore = Ext.create('YourApp.store.TemplateStore');

        templateStore.on('load', function() {
            me.totalAllocation = templateStore.proxy.reader.rawData.totalAllocation;
        }

        me.viewConfig.itemTpl = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<div>',
                '<span>{fundName}</span>',
                '<span>{[this.getPercentage(values.allocation)]}%</span>',
            '</div>',
            {
                getPercentage: function (allocation) {
                    return Ext.Number.toFixed(allocation / me.totalAllocation, 2);
                }
            }
        )
        templateStore.load();
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: The store has rootProperty set to 'document.fundAllocation' and successProperty set to 'document.success'. And as I understand you simply propose declaring a global variable with a value for totalAllocation that will be available everywhere? And that we have to update that global variable each time we load new data into the store?

Comment: Definitely NOT a global variable, I assumed that you are creating this `itemTpl` from inside an `initComponent` call on a view. The `totalAllocation` variable would be scoped to the `initComponent` function for that instance of the view. If the store is not already loaded when you instantiate the class then that could create a problem. You could easily work around that by assigning `totalAllocation` as a property of that instance of the view. I can give an example like that if you would like.

Comment: I made the answer clearer and added another example. If you are not using a class structure (like MVC pattern shown in the examples above) and doing this in plain old HTML+JS I can give an example like that too if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it looks like the example given is for Ext.js. The itemTpl is defined in view's config for the xtype: 'list'. So it looks like I should move that to the view's initialize method, so that totalAllocation is accecible from inside the template member function closure.